# Add bass pedals to Yamaha Tyros5 76

Tags: keyboard

I want to attach my 13-note pedal board to my Tyros5 76 keyboard. I would be pleased for any information as to how to set up the pedal board to use the keyboard's internal sounds.

Answer ref setting bass pedals to tyros 5 76. Pedals look like crumar( no name on)have plugged in midi out to midi in on KB..pedals have on side push button for midi channels/sustain/transpose . At a loss how to set KB to use internal sounds on pedals.

Comment: I've edited your question in an attempt to clarify its meaning. However, if I've misunderstood, my changes can be removed.

Comment: What pedalboard? What kind of connections does it have? What did you try?

Comment: Is the pedalboard MIDI?